# How to use View with the same functionality multiple times in other Views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am not sure if this is the correct question to ask but I don't know how else I could ask it.

In my project I have a LogInViewModel.cs

```
class LogInViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    public LogInViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

a MenuViewModel.cs

```
class MenuViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    public LogInViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

the Views for both LogInView.xaml and MenuView.xaml are

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    <local:NumPad/>
</StackPanel>
```

NumPad.xaml is a UserControl that has 2 buttons.

What I want is when I click one of the buttons in LogInView I want to set the text of LogInViewModel to some string and when I click one of the buttons in MenuView I want to set the text of MenuViewModel to some string. I want to create a UserControl keyboard view with multiple buttons and be able to use it in multiple views but have it add characters(string) to the TextBox in the View they are located, I could create ICommands for every button in my ViewModels like so

```
class LogInViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    public ICommand SetTextCommand1 { get; set; }
    public ICommand SetTextCommand2 { get; set; }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    public LogInViewModel()
    {
        SetTextCommand1 = new BaseICommand(SetText1);
        SetTextCommand2 = new BaseICommand(SetText2);
    }

    private void SetText1(object obj)
    {
        Text = "1";
    }

    private void SetText2(object obj)
    {
        Text = "2";
    }
}
```

and NumPad.xaml would be

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding SetTextCommand1}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding SetTextCommand2}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and add the same ICommands to MenuViewModel, but it does not seem right because I want my NumPad.xaml to be a keyboard eventually with lots of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you would like to stick with commands, using single command + control it with parameter is better option, e.g.:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding SetTextCommand}" CommandParameter="1" />
    <Button Command="{Binding SetTextCommand}" CommandParameter="2" />
</StackPanel>
```

with

```
class LogInViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    public ICommand SetTextCommand { get; set; }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    public LogInViewModel()
    {
        SetTextCommand1 = new BaseICommand(SetText);
    }

    private void SetText(object obj)
    {
        Text = obj?.ToString();
    }
}
```

Anyway, I would advice to refactor the solution to something cleaner, meaning e.g.:

- your NumPad control shall define public event or command (like KeyPressed)
- the control that embeds NumPad control (LogInView & MenuView in your case) shall explicitly use/bind the event or command of the NumPad
- buttons in the NumPad xaml should use NumPad control's API only; specifying data binding in the reusable control in the way you did is similar to using "magic strings" (e.g. you have to make sure that each ViewModel must define command with the "SetTextCommand" name, it's simply error prone)

So that at the end, you use NumPad similar to:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    <local:NumPad KeyPressed="{Binding SetTextCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```